# Ninject dependency for wcf error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, ninject, ninject-extensions

I have been using Ninject for quite some time now with Asp.Net MVC projects and has worked like a charm. But now, when I want to use the same with a WCF Service Library, by installing `Ninject.Extensions.Wcf` and `Ninject.Web.Common` instead of `Ninject.MVC3`, I am getting below error on adding service reference.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The service type provided could not be loaded as a service because it does not have a default (parameter-less) constructor. To fix the problem, add a default constructor to the type, or pass an instance of the type to the host.
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.InstanceBehavior..ctor(DispatchRuntime dispatch, ImmutableDispatchRuntime immutableRuntime)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime..ctor(DispatchRuntime dispatch)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchRuntime.GetRuntimeCore()
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelDispatcher.OnOpened()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
at Microsoft.Tools.SvcHost.ServiceHostHelper.OpenService(ServiceInfo info)
```

This is my WCF class constructor -

```
    private TestDBContext _dbContext;

    public TestService(TestDBContext ctx)
    {
        _dbContext = ctx;
    }
```

And here is how I add the dependency in NinjectWebCommon -

```
kernel.Bind<TestDBContext>().To<TestDBContext>().InRequestScope();
```

What else is required here? How to fix it?

Thanks

**Edit**: The entire NinjectWebCommon

```
    private static readonly Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();

    /// <summary>
    /// Starts the application
    /// </summary>
    public static void Start() 
    {
        DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestHttpModule));
        DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(NinjectHttpModule));
        bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Stops the application.
    /// </summary>
    public static void Stop()
    {
        bootstrapper.ShutDown();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates the kernel that will manage your application.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The created kernel.</returns>
    private static IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        try
        {
            kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
            kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();

            RegisterServices(kernel);
            return kernel;
        }
        catch
        {
            kernel.Dispose();
            throw;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Load your modules or register your services here!
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="kernel">The kernel.</param>
    private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        kernel.Bind<TestDBContext>().To<TestDBContext>().InRequestScope();
    }
```

**App.config**

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ad0da985773c145f2b30

Comment: This looks pretty straight forward, but theres is still not description of how the WCF service is bootstrapped, like with a *.svc file and/or web.config.

Comment: It is a wcf library, so does not contain .svc. It is bootstrapped using App.config. Let me know which part of that is required for your debugging.

Comment: Good. Could you add the app.config here to? I think its a problem with the factory.

Comment: Does this help in any way - https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Wcf/wiki/Configure-wcf-service-library  ? Want to confirm before jumping to it.

Comment: Add this and my best guess is it should work. I'll just update my answer to clarify a bit.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is due to Ninject not being bootstrapped correctly. When the WCF bootstrapping can't find a parameterless constructor it throws this exception.

Try removing the parameter `TestDBContext ctx` from your `TestService` and see if it will work, just as a test.

To solve the issue, you should ensure that Ninject is indeed setup correctly for WCF.
Adding following to your **web.config**:

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment>
    <serviceActivations>
        <add factory="YourNamespace.NinjectFileLessServiceHostFactory" service="YourNamespace.TestService" relativeAddress="./TestService.svc"/>
    </serviceActivations>
</serviceHostingEnvironment>
```

Also creating the factory:

```
public class NinjectFileLessServiceHostFactory : NinjectServiceHostFactory
{
    public NinjectFileLessServiceHostFactory()
    {
        SetKernel(NinjectWebCommon.Bootstrapper.Kernel);
    }
}
```

To make the Bootstrapper available here you should change it to public access in NinjectWebCommon. Aslo remember to add the required binding in RegisterServices:

```
public static class NinjectWebCommon
{
     public static readonly Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();

     // ...

     private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
     {
         kernel.Bind<ServiceHost>().To<NinjectServiceHost>();
         // ...
      }
 }
```

Comment: I know it will work if I remove the parameter, but that is not the question. I am looking to use the dbcontext in the wcf library, so approaching Ninject way.

Comment: I'm sorry, I think you misunderstood me. I was not proposing to remove as a solution, rather just to test that it works. Because it works without it confirms the problem is indeed WCF not using Ninject for creating the service.

Comment: Yes, it works after removing parameter. I tested that earlier.

Comment: Okay, great. To find the solution to Ninject not being loaded correctly I think you extend the description of your setup in the question. Like how you've setup the service if not through .svc files and how your bootstrapping code looks.

Comment: I have pasted the ninjectwebcommon file which does bootstrapping.